# How to disable automatic High Sierra download?

Tags: macos, software-update, auto-update

I'm happy with my Sierra (10.12.6), but the macOS downloads High Sierra in the background automatically and it takes over 5 GBs of my SSD. Every time I delete High Sierra image from Applications it keeps redownloading itself. How can I stop this madness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Preferences → App Store and disable ‘Download newly available updates in the background’.

Comment: I think it works only before macOS starts downloading the new update(s), because I ticked it off and yet I'm getting constant "Your disk is almost full", while this morning I had 3 GBs free. I'm 99% sure it's High Sierra, can I find the image somewhere? It's not in the Applications as it hasn't been downloaded yet.

Comment: @Wordpressor You can find partial downloads in numerical folders located in `open /private/var/folders/*/*/C/com.apple.appstore` (run in Terminal).

Comment: Thank you, somehow I run that command and the directory was almost empty but once I opened it it freed over 6 GBs on my SSD. Magic :)